# Need to redirect after back button pushed. How?

Tags: javascript, html, back-button

I have a set of three apps/scripts.

The first allows the user to select a value.  That value is passed to the second script, which takes the value, reads a database, and produces XML which is then posted to an Eclipse/Java/RAP application immediately, without user intervention using Javascript "onload'.

After the RAP application is loaded, to the user the back button doesn't seem to work. The back button takes the user to the second script, which gets the same values it did the first time and then immediately forwards to the RAP application again.

We want the back button to work as the user expects, i.e. to take the user back to the first script.

Since using the back button submits exactly the same information as it did in the first pass, including the referrer, the only way I can see to do this is to use cookies.

Is that it, or is there a better way?

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: you can try history.js library. With its API you can set your action to `back` button. https://github.com/balupton/History.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page B set a cookie

On page A, detect the cookie. If it exists, clear the cookie then redirect.

One issue: Page A doesn't know if you got there by pressing BACK or if you navigated there directly. If you can live with that, it will work.

Comment: That's what I was thinking of, and it works.  Was just hoping not to have to use cookies.  Thanks.